# ASP.NET MVC3 Postback brings up new TAB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

net MVC View. At the end of the view I have the following Buttons

```
<div style="clear: both; padding-top: 40px; width: 720px;">
            <button name="buttonHelp" value="Help"  onclick="window.open('Help.htm',target='_blank');return false;"> 
                Help</button>
            <span style="float: right;">
                <button name="button" value="Reset">
                    Reset</button>
                <button name="button" value="Save">
                    Save</button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

The Save and Reset causes a postback and the screen gets refreshed properly.

If I click the help button it opens the Help screen in s new TAB which is what I require.
Now after using the help screen I press Save/Reset it always open a new window which I dont want and I find puzzling.
Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: you may want to avoid button element - they have some compatibility issues - see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/button You may also consider using styled link(anchor tag) for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change solved the problem. the help still opens in  a new tab as I wanted

```
>     <button name="buttonHelp" value="Help" 
> onclick="window.open('Help.htm');return false;"> 
>                 Help</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that the target isn't staying "_blank" after you click Help and that the target of the form is _self.